# How can I change my local main branch identical to github upstream?

Tags: git, github, git-reset

I'm new to using git. I have a branch (develop) cloned from GitHub. I made some changes to the code then I staged them to commits and created a new branch (Remove_Annotations). Then I realised I should have created a new branch first and then staged them for commits in the new branch. Now, my develop branch has the changes I made which I do not want. Is there any way to revert the changes I made in develop branch locally to make it look like my GitHub upstream?

I read about using `git reset --hard @{u}` which would make the local branch look like my upstream. I am not sure whether using `git reset --hard` for the develop branch is the right way. I do not want to do anything to the Remove_Annotations branch.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first create the new branch based on your current branch, and push this branch to the remote repository.

```
git checkout -b new_feature
git push origin new_feature
```

Then checkout to your develop branch, and reset this branch to the old version

```
git checkout develop
git log # select which history version you want to reset
git reset --hard <the history version you selected>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard reset is one option here:

```
# from your branch 'feature'
git reset origin/feature
```

This would reset your local `feature` branch to the local tracking version `origin/feature`.  This tracking branch would be in sync with the true remote tracking branch assuming you have done a `git fetch` lately.  If you are unsure, you could try fetching first:

```
# again, from 'feature'
git fetch origin
git reset origin/feature
```